# Append submit button to input

Tags: html, css

I have an input of type button that is used to validate a form an input of type text.

I have seen that, for example, bootstrap lets you append some values to input. I am wondering how would I do append this input of type button into my input of type text.

I have added a screenshot of how I am thinking of it to be, but I am not sure which CSS strategy I would choose.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Why not open up your console and look at how bootstrap did it?

Comment: Unless I'm really misunderstanding, I think the `button` is *next to* the `input`, not *appended to* it (which would imply the `button` was *within* the `input` element, which it can't be).

Answer (score 2):

It is nothing but a submit button with a text field

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NSA2e/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <input type="text" />
   <input type="button" value="Demo" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

input[type=text] {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

input[type=button] {
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```